# Django/Tastypie - Set theory queries (intersection, etc.)

Tags: django, tastypie, intersection, set-theory

I have simple models where users have files they need to rate.
I use Django/tastypie.

`[models.py]`

```
class User( models.Model ):
    [..]

class File( models.Model ):

    [..]
    bVerified = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, )

class UserFile( models.Model ):

    [..]
    nRate = models.CharField( max_length=4)
    user = models.ForeignKey( User, related_name="userfile" )
    file = models.ForeignKey( File, related_name="userfile" )
```

`[api.py]`

```
class UserFileResource( MyModelResource ) :

    user = fields.ToOneField( 'app.api.UserResource','user',full=True,null=True)
    file = fields.ToOneField( 'app.api.FileResource','file',full=True,null=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = UserFile.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'userfile'
        filtering = {
            "id" : ALL,
            "file" : ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            "user" : ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }
    def apply_filters(self, request, applicable_filters):
        oBaseObject = super( UserFileResource, self ).apply_filters( request, applicable_filters )
        loQ = []
        idUser = str( request.user.id )
        loQ.append( Q( **{ 'user__id__exact' : idUser } ) )
        loQ.append( Q( **{ 'file__bVerified__exact' : 1 } ) )
        oFilter = reduce( operator.and_, loQ )
        oBaseObject = oBaseObject.filter( oFilter )
        return oBaseObject
```

With above code this is the result set I currently get, i.e. all my (john's) files:

```
{
"meta": { "limit": 10, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 3 },
"objects": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nRate" : 5,
        "file": { "name": "test1.txt", "bVerified": 1 },
        "user": { "id": 1, "name": "john" }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nRate" : 3, 
        "file": { "name": "test2.txt", "bVerified": 1 },
        "user": { "id": 1, "name": "john" }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "nRate" : 4, 
        "file": { "name": "test3.txt", "bVerified": 1 },
        "user": { "id": 1, "name": "john" }
    }
]
}
```

I now want to make three "set theory" queries with defined users.
I (John) want to compare my files with two other users (Tim and Tom)

Those are the results I would like to get for three types of queries:

Files only I (john) have :

```
{
"meta": { "limit": 10, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 1 },
"objects": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "file": { "name": "test3.txt", "bVerified": 1 },
        "user": [
            { "id": 2, "name": "john", "nRate" : 4 }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Files I (john) don't have but the others (tim and tom) do :

```
{
"meta": { "limit": 10, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 2 },
"objects": [
    {
        "id": 23,
        "file": { "name": "test42.txt", "bVerified": 1 },
        "user": [
            { "id": 2, "name": "tom", "nRate" : 7 },
            { "id": 3, "name": "tim", "nRate" : 7 }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 24,
        "file": { "name": "test43.txt", "bVerified": 1 },
        "user": [
            { "id": 2, "name": "tom", "nRate" : 7 },
            { "id": 3, "name": "tim", "nRate" : 7 }
        ]
    }

]
}
```

Files we all have:

```
{
"meta": { "limit": 10, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 1 },
"objects": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "file": { "name": "test1.txt", "bVerified": 1 },
        "user": [
            { "id": 1, "name": "john", "nRate" : 5 },
            { "id": 2, "name": "tom", "nRate" : 4 },
            { "id": 3, "name": "tim", "nRate" : 7 }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Anyone did something like this already or can share some approach?